# OnClick add items from one page to another (Ionic 2 + Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am currently building a recipe app and I want to add a shopping list page whereby you click "Add to shopping list" button and it will take the ingredients listed in a `<ul>` and post them onto the page I want, they will need to be removed and marked as complete if possible. Essentially a shopping cart without any prices.

My ingredients are being pulled from an API (http get) and printed as below.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

If someone could show me an example or help me out it would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: what is your ingredients click call that calls the page for ingredientLines ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by maintaining a data structure and pass it as a parameter to next page/store it in the local storage/submit to database and pull from there on the required page.

You will make changes to this structure after you click on any of the item using `(click)='myFunc()'` kind of code.

E.g.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines">
    <li (click)='myFunc()>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

In you `myFunc()` you can manipulate your data structure. E.g. add/maintain a property saying `addedToCart=true` kind of code.

Very simple. Hope this helps. Can help with specifics if you have any.